# Add a menu to a java swing application

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java swing application, and I want to get a menu like that:

[image: MENU]

I created the first menu (on the top) using a JMenuBar and JMenuItems, but I don't know how to create the second one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried already.

Comment: Find it here [Tutorial - How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could try making a `JToolBar` and then add buttons to it.

Comment: OK, but is there a component in Java swing designed to do this like JMenuBar ?

Comment: @Ben03: he **told** you the component!

Comment: @Ben03 What do you mean? JToolBar is a Swing component. Here is a tutorial on it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JTabbedPane` and for each element one tab.
**UPDATE:**

[Here](http://www.javacoderanch.com/how-to-add-icon-to-jtabbedpane-tabs.html) you find a simple example of tabs with icons

Comment: with JTabbedPane, I cannot use icons and text as shown in the image I posted I guess.

Comment: Use the `setIconAt` method of the `JTabbedPane`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just horizontally align buttons. But make it your own horizontal menu component with dynamic itens and a flexible interface.